# Which one is better when select the last entry of an ordered map in c++

Tags: c++, ordered-map

1. `auto& myKey = myMap.rbegin()->first;`
2. `auto& myKey = std::prev(myMap.end())->first;`

`myMap` is a constant ordered map. 
Both of the approaches are with constant complexity. `rbegin()`uses reverse iterator, while `std::prev`works on bidirectional iterator. Any efficiency difference between them?

Comment: This would seem to be more of a personal preference than anything else. Personally 2 is easier to follow for me.

Comment: "`rbegin()` usese reverse iterator, while [`myMap.end()`] works on bidirectional iterator" - I think this statement confuses iterator types with iterator categories. These are both iterators with bidirectional traversal capabilities, iterating over logically-different ranges. I'm mentioning this as the statement might be understood as one call returning an iterator that is more complex than the other one.

Comment: Don't know the bigger problem, but you might want to use a `std::map` with inverted ordering instead, i.e. using a comparison functor that calls `!std::less(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The typical implementation for `rbegin()`:

```
reverse_iterator rbegin()
{
    return reverse_iterator(end());
}
```

This is essentially the same as doing `std::prev(myMap.end())`.  So, theoretically they would be identical.  However, the `reverse_iterator` tends to be a little tougher on compiler optimizers.  If you care much, I would suggest tracing through the actual release-mode assembly (or generate assembly output) in your compiler and see if there is a difference.